# How do I create a new MongoDB from the command line with auth turned on?

Tags: mongodb, capistrano

For the purpose of wanting to create a MongoDB database in a Capistrano task, I need to figure out how to create a new database via the MongoDB shell when MongoDB is running with auth turned on.

With auth turned on the MongoDB shell can't do anything without first authenticating, but authenticating has to happen while using the **admin** database as far as I'm aware. So I've been connecting to it for starters like:

```
sudo -u mongodb mongo admin --eval "db.auth(username, password)"
```

And that authenticates me for further action but...at that point I need to create the database, and a user for it in the same shell session. I can't however:

```
sudo -u mongodb mongo admin --eval "db.auth(username, password);use new_database"
```

Because `use database` can't be used in eval. So I've tried instead:

```
sudo -u mongodb mongo admin --eval "db.auth(username, password);db = connect('localhost:27017/new_database')"
```

And that will actually get me an instance of the new database I want created but if I try to:

```
sudo -u mongodb mongo admin --eval "db.auth(username, password);connect('localhost:27017/new_database').addUser(new_user, new_password)"
```

I get an authentication error, so apparently using the `connect()` command forgets that I've authenticated before.

So this is where I'm stuck, trying to create a database in one line with MongoDB using auth and an admin user.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [db.getSiblingDB(name)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getSiblingDB/) to reference the new database and add a new account, eg:

```
mongo -u username -p password admin --eval "db.getSiblingDB('new_database').addUser('new_user', 'new_password');"
```

Now you should be able to authenticate from the command line using -u and -p:

```
mongo -u new_user -p new_password new_database
```

Comment: @kschaper: Thanks, corrected the docs link (from the old wiki link).

Answer (score 6):

Beware of the fact that `addUser` function got deprecated since version 2.6.

Use `db.createUser()` and `db.updateUser()` instead of `db.addUser()` to add users to MongoDB.

Your code should be like below :

```
mongo -u username -p password admin --eval "db.getSiblingDB('new_database').createUser({ user : 'new_user', pwd :  'new_password', roles : [{ role: 'readWrite', db: 'new_database'}]});"
```